# python: rows from a textfile

Tags: python, text-files

**I want to save the whole output of test.py in an array. How can I do this?**

test.txt

```
1.0  0.0  3.0
2.0  0.5  0.0

6.0  4.0  2.0
1.0  0.0  3.0
```

test.py

```
a = [0,1]

with open('test.txt') as fd:
    for n, line in enumerate(fd):
        if n in a:
            t = numpy.array(line.split())
            print(t)
```

Output:

```
['1.0' '0.0' '3.0']
['2.0' '0.5' '0.0']
```

print beyond the loop:

```
print(t)
```

Output beyond the loop:

```
['2.0' '0.5' '0.0']
```

How can I get something like this?

```
[['1.0' '0.0' '3.0']
['2.0' '0.5' '0.0']]
```

Comment: So you only want to read the first two lines and save them as a list of lists?

Comment: no I wanted to read the first two lines and save it as an array. I want to get a matrix 2x3 out of them

Comment: Python doesn't have a built-in array type. You can use `array` or `numpy` modules. If you want to use a list then you can create an empty list and append each line.

Comment: is it not possible to get a 2x3 matrix out of them?

Comment: or how can I append these together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know the size ahead of time, you can append to a list instead, then convert to numpy array.

```
import numpy as np
a = [0,1]
d = []
with open('test.txt') as fd:
    for n, line in enumerate(fd):
        if n in a:
            d.append(line.split())

np.asarray(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer for your question is published in the following post: [How to read a file line-by-line into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list)

Summing up the solution from @SilentGhost for your code:

```
with open('test.txt') as fd:
    t = fd.readlines()
t = [x.strip() for x in t]
```

Comment: He wants to store his in-memory list to a file in a format similar to array.